Correct interpretation of survival curves that eventually meet
I have some survival data that we are trying to analyse and make sense of. The outcome is a progression in disease status. The primary exposure is time-varying in nature - initially unexposed, but once exposed we have considered them to remain so until progression or censoring. So our data is in start, stop format - that's all fine.
I am increasingly being attracted to using flexible parametric survival models, for their simplicity in use and additional information they can provide above and beyond the Cox model. The flexible parametric model we ended up using for this analysis essentially reduced to a Weibull in terms of the shape of the log cumulative baseline hazard, but we did incorporate an interaction (time-varying coefficient) for the main exposure as it was shown to have non-proportional hazards.
So the hazard ratio varies with time.
The Kaplan Meier and HR plots over time are attached.
The survival curves seem to come together after about 17 years and the HR suggests the exposure is protective for the outcome for only the first 5 years or so.
Is the correct way to interpret this something along the lines of there being benefit for a short period of time in the exposure preventing the outcome (relative to unexposed), but given enough time, everyone ends up with the same level of disability?
If that's the case, I guess you can still rationalise the exposure provides benefit in terms of interim quality of life even if the net eventual effect is neutral?




... the HR suggests the exposure is protective for the outcome for only the first 5 years or so

That seems like a reasonable interpretation

The survival curves seem to come together after about 17 years

Be very cautious when trying to interpret late times in survival curves. With fewer cases at risk than at earlier times, the precision in estimates at late times can be poor.
See below for my interpretation.
Two other things to consider.
First, if the outcome is progression of disease status and the time scale is in decades, as in your data, then you might need to consider a competing-risks model with death as a competing risk. That's less of an issue if you consider death to be "progression of disease status."
Second, you probably should be considering a cure model rather than a simple parametric survival model. A simple parametric survival model implicitly assumes that all individuals eventually experience the event; the baseline survival curve necessarily goes down to 0 at late times.
Your data, however, show that about half of all individuals never experience disease progression. I suspect that your parametric models aren't capturing that important aspect of your data. A "cure model" jointly estimates cure (of some) and survival curves (of others) as functions of predictors.
My alternative interpretation of your data: a large fraction of individuals never show disease progression and are "cured." The assumption of simple parametric models, that the baseline survival curve reaches 0 at late times, only applies to those who aren't "cured." Based on the survival curves, it's possible that more of those who received the intervention were "cured" than those who didn't, but as I said above it can be hard to interpret late times on survival curves.

Thanks @EdM. I always hope I'm lucky enough to have you respond to one of my questions. I will go away and read about cure models which are completely foreign to me at the moment.
